# How to fill up each column of a Frequency histogram with points in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I was wondering how I could vertically fill up each rectangle (i.e., column/bar) of a Frequency histogram with points in R?

**The R code below, provides an example.** For clarity, the number these points within each histogram column needs to be equal to the Frequency of that column?

```
h = hist( x = rnorm(1e3), axes = F, labels = T )

axis(2, at = as.integer(seq(0, max(h$counts), len = 5)), las = 1 )

axis(1, at = seq(min(h$breaks), max(h$breaks), len = length(h$breaks) ) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution creating a dataframe to store the point coordinates:

```
set.seed(555)
x = rnorm(1e3)
h = hist( x = x, axes = F, labels = T )
point_df = data.frame(
    x = unlist(sapply(1:length(h$mids), function(i) rep(h$mids[i], each = h$counts[i]))),
    y = unlist(sapply(h$counts, function(c) 1:c))
)
points(point_df$x, point_df$y)
```

Comment: A follow-up question on your answer, what if the original histogram was a density histogram like so: `h = hist( x = rnorm(1e3), axes = F, labels = T, freq = F)`, How would we, then, draw the points?

Comment: When creating `point_df` you could instead do `y = unlist(sapply(1:length(h$mids), function(i) seq(0, h$density[i], length.out = h$counts[i])))`

Comment: Thank you very much, for your first original solutions that uses `counts`, I *sometimes* get an error message from the `data.frame` that says length of `x` and `y` differ?   Please run a few times using `x = rnorm(1e3)` as your input vector (without using `set.seed`). `Error in data.frame(x = unlist(lapply(1:length(h$mids), function(i) rep(h$mids[i],  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 102`